# JQuery .html() failed to work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I tried to load test.html in Chrome but saw nothing. But in Firefox, I was able to see the work "haha". It looks like the JQuery .html() doesn't work in Chrome. I need a remedy. Thanks.

test.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $.get(
          'contents.html',
          function(data){
            $('#samplep').html(data);
          });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="samplep">
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

contents.html:

```
<b>haha</b>
```

Comment: Are you on a web server, or are you running these files locally on your filesystem? If you are not using a web server, the behavior of AJAX may be different across browsers for security purposes. Try uploading these files to a web host of some kind and testing there.

Comment: @NelsonLaQuet Exactly what I was thinking.  Google chrome blocks access to files stored on your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on your computer google chrome disallows access to your computers files.  It a security measure and although annoying is probably the right decision.

There is no bug in JQuery, google chrome is just blocking access.

You could probably right a work around that embeds it in an iframe, but it is not worth the time and effort.

I advise downloading xammp or apache so you can access you own computer by http://localhost.

Comment: Thanks. I was suspecting that but then needed someone to confirm for me.